# Forceful release of Mosek license (directly from its License server)

Tags: mosek

We are using Mosek Floating License offering across our organization.

Sometimes situations occur wherein a team member is unavailable, but has occupied the Mosek licenses, making it unavailable for others (even if urgently required).

To help in those situations, does Mosek's have any utility to forcefully release that occupied license?

e.g.
If utility for License view: `lmutil lmstat -c 27007@127.0.0.1 -a.`, then  what will be the utility for License release?

Comment: If that happens a lot you could also agree to set the parameter "cache_license" to "off" and then the license is returned right after optimization so it is occupied the minimal required time. https://docs.mosek.com/latest/pythonapi/guidelines-optimizer.html#the-license-system

Comment: Yeah, **cache_license=off** would definitely be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consult

https://docs.mosek.com/generic/fnp_LicAdmin.pdf

for question about the license system.

You should do

lmutil lmremove something

(It is in Chapter 12.)

Comment: We used: **./lmutil lmremove -c path/to/mosek.lic feature user user_host display** and it works, Though occasionally it errors out by saying: **"lmremove: lmremove request before the minimum lmremove interval. (-64, 200)"**.

Comment: If possible, can you tell on: 1) Which "interval" is being mentioned here?. 
2) what is the value of that interval?

Comment: I think the system says you are trying to remove a license too often and hence it is a fraud protection feature I suppose.  You can also read about the error codes in the manual.

Comment: Btw it is not normal to use lmremove .  It should only be needed in cases where the application using Mosek exits abnormally. Therefore, the usage of this command is suspicious.

Comment: Yeah, totally understand that.